# Access nested object JSON array with Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, google-apps-script

Using `Logger.log(response.data.phone)`, I'm getting this in my log:

```
[{label=work, primary=true, value=5558675309}, {label=work, value=6108287680, primary=false}, {value=6105516373, label=work, primary=false}]
```

What I want is to return the two phone numbers as `5558675309, 6108287680`.

I've tried `Logger.log(response.data.phone.value)` and that doesn't work. I've tried `...phone['value']`, I've tried `...phone[0].value` and this one does return the first phone number `5558675309`. But I would like it to return all of the `value` values whenever I put in the `phone` key. So how would I modify the logger?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I access and process nested objects, arrays or JSON?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922383/how-can-i-access-and-process-nested-objects-arrays-or-json)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`response.data.phone` is an array you can try looping through it:

```
Logger.log(response.data.phone.map(phone => phone.value).join(', '));
```

```js
const response = {data: {phone : [{label:'work', primary:true, value:5558675309}, {label:'work', value:6108287680, primary:false}, {value:6105516373, label:'work', primary:false}] } }

const Logger = { log : console.log};

Logger.log(response.data.phone.map(phone => phone.value).join(', '));
```

Answer (score 1):

`response.data` is an array, `response.data.phone` does not exist. What you want is `response.data[n].phone` for an integer `n`. You can do this with a `forEach` loop.

```
response.data.forEach((element) => Logger.log(element.phone.value));
```

If for whatever reason you need support for older browsers you can use the older function syntax:

```
response.data.forEach(function(element){
    Logger.log(element.phone.value)
});
```